# Is this structure correct? “What have we to lose by trying to work together to find those solutions?”

Tags: sentence-construction

1. > What **have we to** lose by trying to work together to find those solutions?
2. > What **do we have to** lose by trying to work together to find those solutions?

I am not sure if both sentences are correct. Or they have different meanings?

Comment: Both are correct, and both express the same meaning. However, the first is less idiomatic than the second, in that it does not employ the auxiliary verb _do_. You should use the second in ordinary discourse; use of the first should be reserved for formal settings, since it exposes the speaker to the risk of being identified as "educated".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both have the same meaning.  However while the second sentence is a "standard" English question, the first sentence inverts the word order in a [*rhetorical*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/rhetorical) style, most often used in [oratory](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/oratory) and public argument, or any kind of *persuasive* speech.  The implication is that the writer (or speaker) is going to *tell* you what we have to lose, or if nothing is presented, that we have *nothing* to lose.

Here's the relevant section from John McCain's speech today on the Senate floor:

> What have we to lose by trying to work together to find those solutions? We’re not getting much done apart. I don’t think any of us feels very proud of our incapacity. Merely preventing your political opponents from doing what they want isn’t the most inspiring work. [(source)](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2017/07/25/full-text-john-mccains-senate-floor-speech/509799001/)

McCain implies that the Senate has *very little* to lose, because it's already not doing much of anything worthwhile.

As with almost anything in English, the exact meaning can vary considerably with context and intonation.

Comment: what does APART mean in "We're not getting much done apart.", btw?thx

Comment: @dan "each on his own"

Comment: @dan _"Apart"_ here means "individually" or "separately".